# Coordinate system transformation in 3D

Tags: 3d, rotation, computer-vision, coordinate-transformation, homogenous-transformation

I have a point cloud of a scene in which one object of interest is present along with some other points. I also know the coordinates of the eight corners of the 3D bounding box which happens to be a cuboid.

Now I have a use case where I need to transform this point cloud into the camera coordinate system where each 3D point will get a new XYZ coordinate. Similarly, the eight corner points of the 3D bounding box should be transformed into the camera coordinate system.

Now I have the extrinsic matrix; (rotation matrix and translation) which converts the column vectors from the camera coordinate system to the world coordinate system. I convert the rotation matrix into the quaternion for simplicity.

I want to convert the point cloud and bounding box coordinates from world coordinate system to the camera coordinate system. So I obtain the inverse transformation by simply taking the inverse rotation and negative translation as follows:

```
void get_inverse_transform( const Eigen::Quaternionf& orientation,
                            const Eigen::Vector3f& translation,
                            Eigen::Quaternionf& inverse_orientation,
                            Eigen::Vector3f& inverse_traslation)
{

    inverse_orientation = orientation.normalize().inverse().normalise();
    inverse_translation = -1*inverse_orientation._transformVector(position);
}
```

Now, `inverse_translation` and `inverse_orientation` holds the transformation which will convert the points in world coordinate system to the camera coordinate system.

So, I transform the eight corners of the bounding box using this transformation into camera coordinates in the following way:

```
void project2CS( const Eigen::Quaternionf& inverse_orientation,
                 const Eigen::Vector3f& inverse_position,
                 std::vector<Eigen::Vector3f>& bbox3d_corners)
{

    for( auto& corner: bbox3d_corners )
    {
        auto transformed_vec = inverse_orientation._transformVector(corner) + inverse_translation;
        corner[0] = transformed_vec[0];
        corner[1] = transformed_vec[1];
        corner[2] = transformed_vec[2];
    }
}
```

I also transform the point cloud into the camera coordinate system and visualize it with the bounding box, the bounding box does not surround the object anymore. Moreover, I see the size of the bounding box change slightly.

I suspect I am doing something wrong in getting the inverse transformation. Any ideas on how to get this work?

Comment: Could you please share some points as well as the bounding box and the original transformation parameters (orientation and the shift vector)?